# Как сделать задвижение обратной формы, после отправки сообщения?

Tags: javascript, html, css

html разметка

```
form.contact-form(enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form")
                table(width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5")
                    tr
                        td(width="70%")
                            input(type='text' class='pole_vvoda' name='name' id='name' placeholder='Ваше Имя...' required='')
                        td(width="15%" id="errOffset") &nbsp;
                    tr
                        td
                            input(type='text' class='pole_vvoda' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Ваш E-mail...' required='')
                        td &nbsp;
                    tr
                        td
                            textarea(name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5" placeholder="Сообщение")
                        td(valign="top") &nbsp;
                    tr
                        td(valign="top") &nbsp;
                    tr
                        td(colspan="2")
                            input(type="submit" name="button" class="button" value="Отправить")
                            input(type="reset" name="button2" class="button" value="Очистить")
```

css

```
.button 
    height: 35px
    width: 80px
    margin-right: 2px
    border: 1px solid #000

.forma1.forma2 
    right: 0
    margin: 0
    position: fixed
    display: flex
    top: 200px
    transition: 600ms

.forma1 
    position: fixed
    right: -250px
    top: 200px
    display: flex
    transition: 600ms
```

js код

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData( this );
    $.ajax({
      url: 'send.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      data: fd,
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Спасибо! Сообщение доставленно.");
      setTimeout(function() {
        form.reset();
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

js при нажатии на кнопку выджвижение

```
$(function(){
  $('div.back_svyaz').click(function(){
    $('div.forma1').toggleClass('forma2');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```
.done(function() {
  alert("Спасибо! Сообщение доставленно.");
  setTimeout(function() {
    form.reset();
    th.trigger("reset");

    $('div.forma1').removeClass('forma2');

  }, 1000);
```